# Store current logged in user id on database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on certain models on my app, in my User Controller i need store logged in user id to know who create/edit certain model, in User i've this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use File;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Verificamos si el email existe y otros datos del usuario
        $user = Auth::user();

        $request->validate([
            // {...}
            'created_by' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        $created_by = Auth::user()->id;

        User::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('user-created','Usuario creado exitosamente.');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Verificamos si el email existe y otros datos del usuaro
        $user = Auth::user();

        // Validamos datos
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            // {...}
        ]);

        // Recogemos los campos del usuario
        // {...}
        $modified_by    = Auth::user()->id;

        $user->fill($data);
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('user.show', $user->id)->with(['user-updated' => 'Usuario actualizado correctamente']);
    }
}
```

In the code, you can see any default resource methods, to manage users. For example:

If User with **ID 1**, and can **create/edit User** (or another model), store the ID on `created_by`, `modified_by` field database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you have **created_by** and **modified_by** column in the **users** table.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use File;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Verificamos si el email existe y otros datos del usuario
        $user = Auth::user();

        $request->validate([
            // {...}
            'created_by' => 'required|string'
        ]);


       //for example you have firstname, lastname, age, and address columns in your users table
        $created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        User::create([
            'firstname' => $request->firstname,
            'lastname' => $request->lastname,
            'age' => $request->age,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'created_by' => $created_by
        ]));

        return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('user-created','Usuario creado exitosamente.');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Verificamos si el email existe y otros datos del usuaro
        $user = Auth::user();

        // Validamos datos
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            // {...}
        ]);

        // Recogemos los campos del usuario
        // {...}
        $modified_by    = Auth::user()->id;

        User::find($id)->update([
             'firstname' => $request->firstname,
             'lastname' => $request->lastname,
             'age' => $request->age,
             'address' => $request->address,
             'modified_by' => $modified_by
         ]));


        return redirect()->route('user.show', $user->id)->with(['user-updated' => 'Usuario actualizado correctamente']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need only id you can use Auth::id()

Answer (score 0):

You can call the user ID by using auth `Auth::user()->id`

you can also call any column on your user using `Auth` just change the id.